# Cordova - How do I call a javascript file when not using index.html

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

My Cordova Android wrapper, is pointing directly to my Ionic Web app through the config.xml file, like this:

```
<content src="https://my-app.com" />
```

I am wanting to call a javascript file once the device is ready (to set some permissions settings). Similar to how the index.html file automatically calls them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

But since I am not using the index.html file, as I am directly pointing to my ionic web app, these never get called. I am specifically wanting to trigger functionality based on the onDeviceReady function. Since Cordova is new to me, I'm not sure where I would put that functionality to get it to trigger on the Android Wrapper side, since the index/cordova/app.js files are not being called. I basically want to trigger a JS file from the Android Wrapper without using the typical index.html file to initiate it. What is the best way for me to do this? Any help or even a different strategy would be appreciated!

Comment: The provided cordova.js that is bundled with the app cannot be exposed to remote sources without breaking the terms of service of the iOS App Store / Google Play store. This is because cordova.js provides a bridge to call on native APIs, and exposing these APIs to code that isn't bundled with the app allows external sources to call on native APIs -- which is a breach to the terms. Additionally, using a remote source as your content launch makes it difficult for you to handle situations where the user might be offline. I'd strongly reconsider your strategy here.

Comment: @NormanBreau Thanks for the answer! I'm not trying to expose it, I just want to run it whenever the app starts without triggering it from index.html. I'm fine with triggering it from inside the wrapper itself, I just can't figure out where I would put the code to launch the cordova.js file.